# how do you import mapbox-gl-draw using webpack?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using create-react-app and trying to install mapbox-gl-draw.

```
npm install @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw
```

This works with some npm warnings. I then try to pull mapbox-gl-draw into a component like this:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
import ReactMapboxGl from 'react-mapbox-gl';
import MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw'

console.log(MapboxDraw)
```

I just get an empty object.

I am using create-react-app. Do I need to use a different webpack .config file.

What is the best way to import mapbox modules like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using webpack, you need to alias to use mapbox-gl dist file, here is how I have done it using webpack2:

```
    resolve: {
      modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.svg'],
      alias: {
        // mapbox-gl related packages in webpack should use dist instead of the default src
        '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw': path.resolve(root, 'node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.js'),
      },
    },
```

Variable "root" was defined earlier in the file to refer to the root directory of the project, on the same level as package.json etc.

The same problem can happen in react-map-gl-alt where you need to alias 'mapbox' to 'node_modules/mapbox/dist/distfilehere.js'.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use mapbox-gl-draw but for my Angular 2/4 app, what is the best way to edit my package.json to in order to user the module properly?

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon [medv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7005626/medv)'s answer, at current, in your package.json, you need to add the mapbox-gl v0.270 - v0.38.0, like:

`"mapbox-gl": ">=0.27.0 <=0.38.0` when using `"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.0.1"`.

This is explained [at the 'Requires' line here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw#mapboxmapbox-gl-draw) & if you look at the `peerDependencies` in the [package.json](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/package.json).